# Cayley-Dickson form of a quaternion

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, rt.representation-theory, terminology, notation

It is known that using the Cayley-Dickson construction a quaternion $q$ can be written in a symplectic form as $q=x+\mathbf{i}y$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$.

I read in a couple of references that $x$ is called the *simplex*-part whereas $y$ is called the *perplex*-part of the quaternion.  Is this widely accepted and if not what is the proper onomatology?

On the same topic is there a standard name for the two quaternion parts comprising an octonion?

Comment: Personally I've never read or heard the terms "simplex part" and "perplex part".

Comment: I'm with Johannes, I've never seen a simplex-part or perplex-part mentioned anywhere...what references used those terms?

Comment: I believe that this might be engineering nomenclature, who also use the term "symplectic" in the same sense as in the question.  I have never come across this usage of symplectic (although I can see why it is used) or "simplex" and "perplex" parts in the mathematics or mathematical physics literature.


Comment: Moreover, I would say that the Cayley-Dickson process would write the quaternion as a *pair* $(x,y)$ of complex numbers and not in the way that it is written in the question.

Comment: I do not know where you got this from, but this is not Cayley-Dickson construction. Instead, the form you give in the question is a representation of bicomplex numbers, which are not quaternions.

Comment: Yes it is. See Bourbaki *Algebra III*, §2, no. 4: Cayley algebras.

Comment: @Anixx: we need to think of the complex numbers as being the real span of $1,j$, not $1,i$, inside the quaternions. Then clearly with $ji=-k$ you can write every quaternion uniquely as $z+iw$ for complex numbers $z=x+jy$ and $w=u+jv$, for real numbers $x,y,u,v$.

Answer (score 6):

I believe there is a good reason why mathematicians don't use the terminology "simplex-part" and "perplex-part": they are not canonical! Indeed, algebraically there is no way to distinguish the elements $i$, $j$ and $k$ in the quaternion algebra $\mathbb{H}$ (and there are in fact many more elements playing the same rôle).

On the other hand, there is a canonical *standard involution* on $\mathbb{H}$, namely
$$\sigma \colon x = a + bi + cj + dk \mapsto \overline{x} := a - bi - cj - dk,$$
and therefore the decomposition of $a + bi + cj + dk$ into the two parts $a$ and $bi + cj + dk$ *is* canonical. The part $bi + cj + dk$ is often called the *pure part* of the element $x$.

(This terminology is also used for octonions, and also for (generalized) quaternion and octonion algebras over arbitrary fields of characteristic different from $2$.)

Comment: googling **"perplex part" quaternion** yields 18 results, including this question.

Comment: googling *"pure part" quaternion* on the other hand yields 579 results. It seems that "purely imaginary part" is used more often, since googling *"purely imaginary part" quaternion* gives 12400 hits.

Answer (score 0):

[1] T. A. Ell and S. J. Sangwine, “Hypercomplex Fourier Transforms of Color Images,” IEEE Transactions on Image Processing, vol. 16, no. 1, pp. 22-35, Jan. 2007.